# Why my HTML/Body size not fitting to screen size for smaller screen (Mobile size)

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Whenever my screen size decreases below ~350 pixels, html and body size is just becoming half and even below of my screen size.
I tried setting HTML and BODY tag width as 100%, 100vw & auto. Still no luck.
I use media query for max-width: 800px for responsiveness. Img: [HTML size for smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgjTg.jpg)

Body styles:

```
body {
  padding: 4rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url("test1.jpg");
  background-position: center; /* Center the image */
  background-size: cover; /* Resize the background image to cover the entire container */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px){
  body {
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

Comment: looks like you are using create-react-app. i've experienced this before. i usually refresh the page entirely when testing different screen sizes. see if that works. if not, you need to post more code so we can help analyze the issue

Comment: Exactly i am using create react app. I tested multiple times post refresh. Still same issue.
Could you plese tell me which part of code required to analyze?
My Github link: https://github.com/DilipAnthony/ecom-website